# Java library to convert Word doc into PowerPoint

Tags: java

I am looking for any Java library which can convert Word doc into PowerPoint format.

I have looked into some libraries such as documents4j which converts many of the formats but not Word doc into PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Apache Poi: https://poi.apache.org.

From their mission statement:

> The Apache POI Project's mission is to create and maintain Java APIs for manipulating various file formats based upon the Office Open XML standards (OOXML) and Microsoft's OLE 2 Compound Document format (OLE2). In short, you can read and write MS Excel files using Java. In addition, you can read and write **MS Word** and **MS PowerPoint** files using **Java**. Apache POI is your Java Excel solution (for Excel 97-2008). We have a complete API for porting other OOXML and OLE2 formats and welcome others to participate.
>
> OLE2 files include most Microsoft Office files such as XLS, **DOC**, and **PPT** as well as MFC serialization API based file formats. The project provides APIs for the OLE2 Filesystem (POIFS) and OLE2 Document Properties (HPSF).

I have extensively used this library with Word and Excel and it is really working well.